# Regular expression for validating ID in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

What is Regular expression for validating ID in C# asp.net?

I'd like to allow only alphabets, numbers and _-.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The purpose of this site isn't to prevent you from opening the documentation to learn how to do the most trivial task.

Comment: What does "only alphabets" mean? Keep this in mind when writing the regular expression, and pay attention to what `\w` means in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
^[\w_-]+$
```

It allows one or multiple numbers, alphabets (upper and lower case), `_`, `-` symbols.

Comment: Hi brothers28, thanks! It works beautifully!!!

Comment: One more person answered to my question and the solution also worked, but the post was deleted... Anyway, I just wanted to thank both brothers28 and the person, you guys rock! :)